# Determine what when multiplied with $180$ gives a perfect cube

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, contest-math

Recently, at a math competition, I was given the following question: Determine the smallest number that gives a perfect cube when multiplied by $180$ . I had thirty seconds to solve this question and no calculator.

The answer was $150$ since $150 \cdot 180=27000$ and $\sqrt[3]{27000}=30$.

I was stuck on this question without a calculator. Using a calculator with graphing and table generating capabilities, one could simply put $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{180x}.$ Then, they could scroll through a table until they found that $f(150)=30$, an integer. However, I don't see how this could be done without a calculator. Even further, if one did have a calculator, how it could be done in thirty seconds.

How could this be done feasibly in thirty seconds without a calculator? Does it just require enough number sense to know that $180$ is a factor of $27000$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$180=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5$; to make a cube you need to multiply by $2\cdot3\cdot5^2=150$, since you need the exponents to be multiples of $3$.

Comment: AH! Should've thought of that...

Comment: @zz20s: I know that feeling well!